# 3d skeleton from segmentation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to create a skeleton based on an existing segmentation, similar to what is done here (from [sk-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_medial_transform.html)):

[image: my goal]

However I want to do this on 3D data. Is there code for that somewhere out there? Preferably in python but any language helps.

I am aware of [this](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~palagyi/skel/skel.html) great site, however I think they don't offer any code.

I am planning on using that on volumes of about 500x500x500 Pixels, so it should scale well...

Comment: There is no much code available for 3D data out there... I don't know if you will find any, but,  what you can try is to look at [scikits-image code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/master/skimage/morphology/_skeletonize.py) (it has a public github repository) and try to program a 3D version of it. If you do, scikits-image are happy to accept code submission to extend the library.

Comment: Prepare to get your hands dirty, this is going to be a tough one! Good luck with coding your 3D skeletonization and please, submit your progress to scikits-image!!

Comment: FWIW, scikit-image implemented 3D skeletonization in 2016. See, e.g., https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/pull/1923#issuecomment-186256466

Answer (score 0):

I am developing this tools in this link below. The function **getSkeletonize3D** in program of the name **convOptimize.py** lets you thin your 3D data. It took about 30 minutes to give the result for the 512 cube I have. Let me know if you have any problems. https://github.com/3Scan/3scan-skeleton. The paper I used for implementing is in the comments in the code below

Basically how this 3D skeletonization algorithm works is, in each pass it has 12 subiterations in which it removes boundaries in specific directions iteratively, until you get a skeleton in the center.

The main python code that is needed for skeletonizing your data is as below. As it requires imports from different other porgrams rotationalOperators which has an import from another file called Thin3dtemplates. I recommend you downlaod rotationalOperators, Thin3dtemplates, convoptimize python scripting files and also download lookuparray.npy which is a file that is used as a lookup table in an numpy array format pre-calculated for validating a voxel for marking to be deleted or not. You need python > 3 version, scipy, numpy and pyeda modules installed to run these codes.

```
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy import ndimage
from scipy.ndimage.filters import convolve

"""
   the following subiteration functions are how each image is rotated to the next direction for removing
   boundary voxels in the order described in the reference paper
   us, ne, wd,..
"""
from rotationalOperators import firstSubiteration, secondSubiteration, thirdSubiteration, fourthSubiteration, fifthSubiteration, sixthSubiteration, seventhSubiteration, eighthSubiteration, ninthSubiteration, tenthSubiteration, eleventhSubiteration, twelvethSubiteration

"""
   reference paper
   http://web.inf.u-szeged.hu/ipcg/publications/papers/PalagyiKuba_GMIP1999.pdf
   input should be a binary image/ already segmented
"""


"""
   array that has calculated the validity of the 14 templates beforehand and stored each index which is
   decimal number of the binary string of 26 values (sqrt(3) connectivity) that are around a single voxel 
"""

lookUpTablearray = np.load('lookupTablearray.npy')


def _convolveImage(arr, flippedKernel):
    arr = np.ascontiguousarray(arr, dtype=np.uint64)
    result = convolve(arr, flippedKernel, mode='constant', cval=0)
    result[arr == 0] = 0
    return result


"""
each of the 12 iterations corresponds to each of the following
directions - us, ne, wd, es, uw, nd, sw, un, ed, nw, ue, sd
imported from template expressions
evaluated in advance using pyeda
https://pyeda.readthedocs.org/en/latest/expr.html
"""

sElement = ndimage.generate_binary_structure(3, 1)


def _getBouondariesOfimage(image):
    """
       function to find boundaries/border/edges of the array/image
    """

    erode_im = ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion(image, sElement)
    boundaryIm = image - erode_im
    return boundaryIm

"""
each of the 12 iterations corresponds to each of the following
directions - us, ne, wd, es, uw, nd, sw, un, ed, nw, ue, sd
imported from template expressions
evaluated in advance using pyeda
https://pyeda.readthedocs.org/en/latest/expr.html
"""

directionList = [firstSubiteration, secondSubiteration, thirdSubiteration, fourthSubiteration,
                 fifthSubiteration, sixthSubiteration, seventhSubiteration, eighthSubiteration,
                 ninthSubiteration, tenthSubiteration, eleventhSubiteration, twelvethSubiteration]


def _skeletonPass(image):
    """
        each pass consists of 12 serial subiterations and finding the
        boundaries of the padded image/array
    """
    boundaryIm = _getBouondariesOfimage(image)
    numPixelsremovedList = [] * 12
    boundaryIndices = list(set(map(tuple, list(np.transpose(np.nonzero(boundaryIm))))))
    for i in range(0, 12):
        convImage = _convolveImage(image, directionList[i])
        totalPixels, image = _applySubiter(image, boundaryIndices, convImage)
        print("number of pixels removed in the {} direction is {}". format(i, totalPixels))
        numPixelsremovedList.append(totalPixels)
    numPixelsremoved = sum(numPixelsremovedList)
    return numPixelsremoved, image


def _applySubiter(image, boundaryIndices, convImage):
    """
       each subiteration paralleley reduces the border voxels in 12 directions
       going through each voxel and marking if it can be deleted or not in a
       different image named temp_del and finally multiply it with the original
       image to delete the voxels so marked
    """
    temp_del = np.zeros_like(image)
    # boundaryIndicesCopy = copy.deepcopy(boundaryIndices)
    lenB = len(boundaryIndices)
    for k in range(0, lenB):
        temp_del[boundaryIndices[k]] = lookUpTablearray[convImage[boundaryIndices[k]]]
    numpixel_removed = np.einsum('ijk->', image * temp_del, dtype=int)
    image[temp_del == 1] = 0
    return numpixel_removed, image


def getSkeletonize3D(image):
    """
    function to skeletonize a 3D binary image with object in brighter contrast than background.
    In other words, 1 = object, 0 = background
    """
    assert np.max(image) in [0, 1]
    zOrig, yOrig, xOrig = np.shape(image)
    padImage = np.lib.pad(image, 1, 'constant', constant_values=0)
    start_skeleton = time.time()
    pass_no = 0
    numpixel_removed = 0
    while pass_no == 0 or numpixel_removed > 0:
        numpixel_removed, padImage = _skeletonPass(padImage)
        print("number of pixels removed in pass {} is {}".format(pass_no, numpixel_removed))
        pass_no += 1
    print("done %i number of pixels in %f seconds" % (np.sum(image), time.time() - start_skeleton))
    return padImage[1: zOrig + 1, 1: yOrig + 1, 1: xOrig + 1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sample = np.ones((5, 5, 5), dtype=np.uint8)
    resultSkel = getSkeletonize3D(sample)
    # gives a single voxel at the center
    print("resultSkel", resultSkel)
```